# The distribution of the sum of sub-exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, orlicz-spaces

I know the sum of sub-gaussian random variables is sub-gaussian, but I want to ask whether the sum of sub-exponential random variables is still sub-exponential random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

We use the definition that $X$ is sub-exponential if there exist $\nu, \alpha > 0$ such that, for all $|\lambda| \leq 1/\alpha$,
$$
\mathbf{E} \exp\{\lambda(X - \mathbf{E} X)\}
\leq e^{\frac{1}{2} \nu^2 \lambda^2}.
$$

Now, let $X_1, X_2$ be sub-exponentials, we can apply Cauchy-Schwarz to compute that, when $|\lambda| \leq 1/(2(\alpha_1 \vee \alpha_2))$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}\exp\{\lambda[(X_1 + X_2) - \mathbf{E}(X_1 + X_2)]\}
&\leq [\mathbf{E}\exp\{2\lambda(X_1 - \mathbf{E} X_1)\} \cdot \mathbf{E}\exp\{2\lambda(X_2 - \mathbf{E} X_2)\}]^{1/2} \\
&\leq \Bigl[\exp\Bigl\{\frac{1}{2} \nu_1^2 (2\lambda)^2\Bigr\} \cdot \exp\Bigl\{\frac{1}{2} \nu_2^2 (2\lambda)^2\Bigr\}\Bigr]^{1/2} \\
&\leq \exp\Bigl\{\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2(\nu_1^2 + \nu_2^2) \lambda^2\Bigr\},
\end{align*}
so that $X_1 + X_2$ is subexponential.
This can then be easily generalised to finite sums.